# how can I check the element type of an array

Tags: swift, swift3

I have an array like this:

```
let arr:[Any] = [1, "wo", true]
```

How can I iterate each element and check the type of each element?

```
for elem : arr {
  // how to check elem type?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print the element type using `type(of:)`:

```
let arr:[Any] = [1, "wo", true]
arr.forEach { (element) in
    print(String(describing: type(of: element)))
}
```

**Output**:
Int
String
Bool

*Or you can use switch case with "is"*

```
arr.forEach { (element) in
    switch element {
    case is Int:
        print("its a Int")
    case is String:
        print("its a String")
    case is Bool:
        print("its a Bool")
    default:
        print("unspecified")
    }
}
```

**Output**: 
its a Int
its a String
its a Bool